# ¿Como sumar o concatenar datos str en de una listas?

Tags: python

Cordial saludo.

tengo una lista con  str en su interior de la siguiente  forma:

```
 l1=['hola  estas','como  Carol','esta  tu   ','aqui  papa ']
```

y quiero que me quede algo así:

```
  l2=['hola-como',  'estas-Carol','esta-aqui', 'tu-papa']
```

cada str de la lista l1 tiene la misma longitud y cada palabra esta separada 
por los mismos espacios.

gracias por su atención.

Comment: Podría darte un código que cree la lista `l2` a partir de la `l1`, pero no entiendo cuál es la pregunta. No veo relación entre la pregunta del título *"concatenar datos str"* con lo que luego quieres, que es algo así *como cortar y combinar palabras*. ¿Puedes explicar mejor lo que necesitas y qué has probado hasta ahora?

Comment: compañero no se si me pregunta esta bien formulada por eso puse un ejemplo. Tengo una lista con n datos str y x palabras, como la del ejemplo pero la del ejemplo es un poco mas corta , efectivamente quiero combinar  palabras como se ve anteriormente. había probado con un for pero lo único que lograba es tomar cada dato y no se como sumar cada palabra y almacenar la combinación en otra lista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No tengo muy claro cómo esperas combinar las palabras de cada elemento `str`. Supongamos que quieres combinar por parejas, de dos en dos:

```
l1=['hola  estas','como  Carol','esta  tu   ','aqui  papa ']

palabras = [s.split() for s in l1]

l2 = [ x+"-"+y for i in range(0,len(l1),2)
                for (x,y) in zip(palabras[i],palabras[i+1]) ]
```

Como te puse en un comentario, el código hace lo que pides. Sirve para cualquier número de elementos y cualquier número de palabras por elemento. Pero tú dirás si es lo que buscabas.

Comment: hola Chema Cortes, gracias por tu respuesta  si es lo que estaba buscando y me dio la solución para la lista que tenia parentesco a l1, pero si no te es  mucha molestia me podrias indicar como aplicarla a esta lista

Comment: hola Chema Cortes, como puedo  aplicarla a esta lista. gracias                                                                                                             l =     [' T_BUSB     T_BUSC     T_BUSA     L_BUSA     L_BUSB\n',     
          ' L_BUSC     H_BUSA     H_BUSB     H_BUSC     SUPLA\n',      
          ' T_BUSA     T_BUSB     T_BUSC     SUPLB      H_BUSA\n'
          ' SUPLA      SUPLB      SUPLC      T_BUSB     T_BUSC\n', 
          ' T_BUSA     TAC_S      TACS       H_BUSB     H_BUSC\n',
          ' H_BUSA     H_BUSB     H_BUSC     T_BUSA     T_BUSB\n']

Comment: Hola, @Yelson-Odoñez. Ya he visto la pregunta que has hecho sobre este mismo tema. Sólo se me ocurre responderte que pruebes a ver qué pasa y nos cuentes qué esperabas que pase.

Answer (score 1):

Esto es una forma para lograr lo que deseas para cualquier cantidad de elementos:

```
l1 = ['hola  estas','como  Carol','esta  tu   ','aqui  papa ']
#Creamos un array donde almacenamos el resultado.
l2 = []
#Dos arrays para almacenar textos de la izquierda y derecha de cada elemento el arreglo original.        
aLeft = []
aRight = []

#Agrega los textos a su correspondiente arreglo, aLeft para textos izquierda, aRight para textos derecha.     
for i in l1:
    aLeft.append(i.split()[0])
    aRight.append(i.split()[1])

for i in range(0, len(aLeft), 2): 
    l2.append(aLeft[i] + "-" + aLeft[i+1])
    l2.append(aRight[i] + "-" + aRight[i+1])

print l2
```

con un resultado:

```
  ['hola-como', 'estas-Carol', 'esta-aqui', 'tu-papa']
```

Comment: Creo que esto solo funciona cuando la lista L1 es de 4 elementos. Asumiría que op quiere algo más general, algo como  `for i in range(0, len(aLeft), 2):
   ....:     l2.append(aLeft[i] + "-" + aLeft[i+1])
   ....:     l2.append(aRight[i] + "-" + aRight[i+1])
   ....:`

Comment: Ah no se como poner ese código en el comentario xD, espero hacerme entender

Comment: Por cierto dices que usas `replace`, pero no lo veo por ahi

Comment: Hola Elenasys, el compañero Javier tiene un poco de razón lo que necesito es como hacer algo mas complejo en el caso que tenga n palabras y m datos, en cada dato no solo puede haber dos palabras pueden haber mas y así mismos no solo pueden haber 4 datos pueden haber mas, puse ese  ejemplo para mirar como podría ser  una solución general y para dar un ejemplo mas o menos de lo que quería.